# Ajax enviando modelo para controller

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu passar um objeto "Model" via ajax para o meu  controller.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("CadastrarSementesVariedades", "SementesLevantamentoVariedades")",
            data: model,
        dataType: "html"
    });
```

Fiz dessa maneira mas não deu certo, teria outra forma de fazer ?

Comment: Olá Samuel, poderia postar o restante do seu código? Somente com isso não  é possível localiza a causa do erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {id: $("#id").val(), descricao: $("#descricao").val()}

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("CadastrarSementesVariedades", "SementesLevantamentoVariedades")",
        data: obj});

public Class Objeto{
   public string id {get; set;}
   public string descricao {get; set;}
}

[httpPost]
public ActionResult CadastrarSementesVariedades(Objeto obj){
   //...
}
```

Dependendo da forma como criou seu formulário, você também pode serializar e enviar direto: data: $("#frm").serialize()